# ATK4 jobeet project

Tags: atk4

I found your doc about jobeet project.
I'm testing (last 4.1b1 version) it step by step, but in day 3 I've error, I think:

1. model Category it'd be

   ```
   class Model_Category extends Model_Table {
       public $entity_code='category';
       public $table_alias='c';
   //...........
   ```
2. model Job it'd be

   ```
   class Model_Job extends Model_Table {
   public $entity_code='job';
   public $table_alias='j';
   //.......
   ```

Right?

1. And now, from here I've error after call generate.html

   ```
   PathFinder_Exception
   Unable to include Model\.php

   Additional information: 

   type: php
   attempted_locations: Array ( [0] => D:/xampp/htdocs/atk4jobeet/lib/Model\.php [1] => D:\xampp\htdocs\atk4jobeet\atk4/lib/Model\.php [2] => D:/xampp/htdocs/atk4jobeet/atk4-addons/mvc/Model\.php [3] => D:/xampp/htdocs/atk4jobeet/atk4-addons/misc/lib/Model\.php )
   ```

Is it problem in class page_generate extends Page_SchemaGenerator?
It waiting for GET[model] param, but day3 write:

If you are willing for Agile Toolkit to generate SQL CREATE code for you, you can set up a page for that. Code generator exists as a class, but you need to enable it in order to use it. Add file page/generate.php with the following content:

```
class page_generate extends Page_SchemaGenerator {}
```

Next navigate to http://localhost/jobeet/generate.html in your browser, pick Category model and click Generate button. The schema code will be shown on the right. You can also click "Generate" checkbox and "create" statement will be evaluated by sql automatically. Once you create 'Category' proceed to create 'Job'.

Where problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually i have done changes for the generator while writing jobeet doc. In your case you can add ?model=Job to the URL. Otherwise you can use git version.

BTW - there is a branch for day3 in the jobeet repository:

https://github.com/romaninsh/jobeet/tree/day3